# Kafka consumer can not read from producer

Tags: apache-kafka

My Kafka consumer can not read messages from producer.

```
$ jps
31700 Kafka
11243 Jps
31517 QuorumPeerMain
```

Feeding topic to producer :

**Before edit** :

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Hello_Kafka
this is my 1st message

this is my 2nd message
```

**After  edit** :

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic Hello-Kafka
this is my 1st message

this is my 2nd message
```

Open another terminal and trying to read data from consumer:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic Hello-Kafka --from-beginning
```

*After this, I do not see any message on the terminal.*

These are some logs which might help to debug :

```
$ [2017-02-20 08:23:15,000] INFO Expiring session 0x15a49f1f2530020, timeout of 30000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:23:15,000] INFO Expiring session 0x15a49f1f2530022, timeout of 30000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:23:15,000] INFO Expiring session 0x15a49f1f2530021, timeout of 30000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:23:15,000] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15a49f1f2530020 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-02-20 08:23:15,000] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15a49f1f2530022 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-02-20 08:23:15,001] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15a49f1f2530021 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,764] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45806 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,766] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:45806 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,768] INFO Established session 0x15a49f1f2530024 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:45806 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,778] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45808 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,778] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:45808 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,779] INFO Established session 0x15a49f1f2530025 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:45808 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,783] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45810 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,783] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:45810 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,784] INFO Established session 0x15a49f1f2530026 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:45810 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,865] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45812 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,865] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:45812 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,867] INFO Established session 0x15a49f1f2530027 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:45812 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-02-20 08:26:48,930] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15a49f1f2530027 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xa9 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-02-20 08:27:50,978] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Comment: "--topic Hello_kafka" vs. "--topic Hello-Kafa" note - vs. _

Comment: You were right, sorry it was my bad. Thanks for your reply. I learnt that I have to be careful while writing kafka topic name. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what version you use: try `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning` -> "bootstrap-server" instead of "zookeeper"